# Popover z-index not applying with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am initializing a popover in the following directive. However when I click on it it still appears under my fixed Bootstrap navbar even though I have set the z-index to 2000, the static navbar is 1030, much less.

Further inspection with dev tools reveals the css z-index is not being applied. Any idea what's going on?

I don't know how much code I need to post for this, so just let me know if you need more.

CSS

```
.popover {
    z-index: 2000 !important;
}
```

JS

```
directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.popovers = {
            somePopover: element.find('.somePopover-btn').popover({
                content: $compile('<anotherDirective></anotherDirective>')(scope),
                html: true,
                title: 'Title'
            })
        };
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };

}]).
```

Comment: Any way you can post a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Does it have the class?

Comment: @ZackArgyle The basic elements of the popover are created by Bootstrap. The content function strictly returns what goes inside. But for what it's worth I have looked at the HTML produced with dev tools and yes, the full html for a popover is being produced with the outer container having the popover class.

Comment: @ZackArgyle Plunker is going to take some time. I will reopen this with a Plunker later.